# wifi card not working on dell latitude D430

Tags: wireless, drivers

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell latitude D430. Most things work fine, but my wireless isn't recognized. My wirelesscard is a combi with bleutooth. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

latitude D430 uses Broadcom chips, it's the usual problem with these chips
First you need to show the output of `lspci -nn` as you have to know the exact chip you using, then get ready to use a cable to get connected to your router

Also you may want to check this link

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless